# Django admin - edit multiple values simultaneously in list display

Tags: django, admin

I have a large number of items and would like to be able to edit a selection of those simultaneously, while in the admin list view.

Here is screen shot of how the action checkbox could be used for this purpose. So, if I edit the importance of one selected item, the importance of all selected items should change simultaneously.

[image]

By also applying `list_filter` and `search_field`, this should speed up edits when dealing with a large number of items.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how this can be done in javascript:

model.py

```
class PlaceName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, db_index=True)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(PlaceType, to_field='code', null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    hasl = models.IntegerField(help_text='Height above sea level')
    importance = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    place_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

admin.py

```
class PlaceNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'importance', 'type', 'area', 'hasl', )
    list_filter = ('area', 'type', )
    readonly_fields = ('name', 'short_name', 'type', 'area',  'lat', 'lon', 'hasl', 'place_id')
    search_fields = ('name', 'importance', 'hasl')
    list_editable = ('importance',)

    class Media:
        js = ('multi_line_list_edit.js',)
```

static/multi_line_list_edit.js

```
(function($) {
    var value_changed = function(jQel) {
        if (jQel.parent().siblings('.action-checkbox').find(':checkbox:checked').length) {
            var value = jQel.val();
            $('#result_list tr').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length)
                    $(this).find('td.field-importance input').val(value);

            });
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#result_list td.field-importance input').change(function () {
            value_changed($(this));
        });
        $('#result_list td.field-importance input').keyup(function () {
            value_changed($(this));
        });
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

You will still have to click the Save button, but by adding some more javascript it would be possible to save the changes just by pressing the Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible solution for you:
in `admin.py`,

```
class importanceAssignerForm(ActionForm):
  importance = forms.IntegerField()

class YourAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
  action_form = importanceAssignerForm
  def assign_importance (self, request, queryset):
    for s in queryset:
      s.importance = request.POST.get('importance')
      s.save()
```

this will show up an importance field next to your actions.

dont forget to add the assign_importance function to your actions.